# Option to disable CSRF validation in KeystoneJs?

Tags: node.js, csrf, keystonejs

Is there a simple way to disable CSRF validation in the KeystoneJS framework?

I ask for development purposes only. Just to avoid having to reload the client every time the server restarts.

If there isn't any exposed configuration option in Keystone, is there a work around in Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't disable the CSRF validation, but if you use your mongo instance as the session store, then you can restart the server to your heart's content without getting the CSRF errors in the Admin UI.

You can use the session store option in your keystone.js file:

```
keystone.init({
    // ...
    'mongo': 'mongodb://localhost/yourdatabase', 
    'session store': 'mongo',
    // ...
});
```